# Дамп большой mysql базы с 30 000 таблиц!

Tags: mysql, dump

У меня база с более чем 30 0000 таблиц, данных в них не много. Не спрашивайте зачем мне столько таблиц(это особенность движка). Понадобилось перенести базу на другой сервер, да и вообще бэкапы делать. Из-за большого кол-ва таблиц возникают проблемы. Дамп через консоль, через программу HeidiSQL занимает около 12 часов (не дождался). Есть ли способ(программа) ускорить дамп такой базы и её восстановление?

Comment: А почему не используете штатные средства? `mysqldump`, например.

Comment: потому что слишком долго

Comment: Значит, развлекайтесь копированием сырых данных. Как - описано в разделе по репликации (там, правда, переносится БД на слейв, но какая разница).

Answer (score 1):

Путем экспериментов, самый быстрый дамп сделал SupexDumperPro, за 15 минут мой дамп. А для своих таблиц нашел решение с выносом их в отдельные базы в зависимости от номеров в названии (у меня они пронумерованы).